# Adding a variable to a layout in Magento

Tags: php, magento, layout, checkout

I’ve added a stage to the one-page checkout in Magento, so as far as I’m aware I have to use code pretty similar to this. What I’m trying to do is add a variable to the layout that I can just echo out.

```
$layout = $this->getLayout();
$update = $layout->getUpdate();
$update->load('checkout_onepage_security');
// My attempt at adding a $test variable:
// $layout->setData('test', 'what is up');
$layout->generateXml();
$layout->generateBlocks();
$output = $layout->getOutput();
return $output;
```

I know how to do it using a block, but this isn’t a block!

Comment: What are you trying to do with this variable? The update object is `Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update`, which does not extend `Varien_Object` and does not have a `__call()` implementation.

Comment: you cannt pass variable to layout only into blocks. Blocks are responsible for the output. So there is no situation where you need to add variable to the layout. In what template do you want to print this var? Layout is like mediator for communication between/with blocks

Comment: Ah I see. Well I’m trying to get a string that’s going to be stored in the session to display in security.phtml, so do I need to put a block in somewhere in order for that to work?